# Handling push notifications on a new iOS application version

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, app-store, push-notification

My current iOS application v1.0 was published to the AppStore and it is receiving push notifications without any problems.

Now I am almost releasing a new version v1.1 for that already published application.

Into version 1.1 I have just introduced a new notification which uses a new `loc-key` value (from the Localizable.strings file).

```
"NEW_NOTIFICATION_LOC_KEY" = "%@ viewed your profile.";
```

As my old application v1.0 does not contains the recently added `loc-key` it is going to present the assigned `loc-key` instead of the desired notification message:

- v1.1 will display `FooUser viewed your profile.`
- v1.0 will display `NEW_NOTIFICATION_LOC_KEY`

What would the best practices be to avoid this undesirable behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't send the new format of push notification until you receive a confirmation that the user has the new version installed.